# replace body content when footer links have changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to protect my copyright links on my themes with javascript or jquery.

```
<div id="footer"><a href="http://example.com" id="example">copyright</a></div>
```

if the footer links or text have changed , then replace body content with my message : "please don't remove my links" .

Comment: If they remove the links, they may also remove the javascript! However if you were to obfuscate the code enough they may not know which piece of code is responsible for adding your message.

Comment: You could use a fancy-pants css thing with !important to make it hard to mess with.

Comment: There really isn't anything you can do to stop a competent theme user from stripping away your copyright link. Placing a comment in your theme's HTML and CSS source files would be better, with something like "Permission is granted to use this theme, with the condition that this copyright notice is retained." On the other hand, putting links back to your own website on websites which use your theme (which may be irrelevant to the content of your website) may be bad for your website's SEO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that would/could work.

Remember that the javscript needs to be called after your footer links have appeared on the page.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="body-content" id="bodyContentId">
    Here is the body content.
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <a href='www.google.com' id="someLink">
      Some Link
    </a>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if( document.getElementById('someLink') == null || document.getElementById('someLink').getAttribute('href') != "www.google.com"){
      document.getElementById("bodyContentId").innerHTML = "Don't remove my links";
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

You could then modify the javascript to reflect your particular links and then pack/obfuscate it with a tool like Dean Edwards' Packer http://dean.edwards.name/packer/

This would bring your code out like this (based on the sample JS above):

Javascript:

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return c.toString(a)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('8(1.0(\'2\')==4||1.0(\'2\').5(\'6\')!="7.3.9"){1.0("a").b="c\'d e f g"}',17,17,'getElementById|document|someLink|google|null|getAttribute|href|www|if|com|bodyContentId|innerHTML|Don|t|remove|my|links'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

As demonstrated in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jH5z4/ by changing/removing the link or changing the address href it will modify the body content.

Comment: how i can convert my js code with not readability for users . like : /4yty54//fg45yt//rd//

Comment: You can use the packer - link in the answer.

Comment: yes but it shown my link , if my link is "stackoverflow" my code will be : |document|someLink|stackoverflow|null|getAttribute|href|www|if|com| - and any one can search and replace it with his link